# Mvc 3 Custom HelperFor, DateTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, html-helper, form-submit

I have a custom helper for a DateTime attribute in my model.

The helper return Html for 3 selects one for day, one for months and the lasts one for years.

I have :

```
        public static MvcHtmlString DateFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
         ...
        }
```

And I'm wondering how to linked the choice of the user when I submit the form into my model dateTime Attribute.

In fact I would like to do the same thing as the EditorFor Helper. If I have for example :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
```

Where userName is a sring. It return a textBox html input and when I submit my form the userName attribute is automatically filled with the field value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom model binder for the DateTime type and a custom editor template to present the UI however you like. Scott Hanselman [`blogged about this`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx). And here's an [`updated version`](http://www.longcloudtech.com/Blogs/Yankiwi/post/2010/04/21/Updating-Scott-Hanselmane28099s-DateTime-Custom-Model-Binder-%28DateAndTimeModelBinder%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could emit a html hidden element alongside the 3 selects and set its initial value to the initial value of the 3 selects (concatenated i.e. dd/mm/yyyy depending on the format applicable to you).

Then you could wire up client side change events to all 3 selects to update the value of the hidden field each time they are changed.

Of course the name of the hidden field has to be the datetime property name (for model binding to kick in).